# Run with interval until condition or a certain time elapsed

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to write a piece of code that is:

1. Run on every configured interval
2. Stops after a certain amount of time OR after a condition is met.

I found that I can use a `Task` with `CancellationToken` but I can't see any option to run a it again and again within an interval.

Another option I saw is to use `System.Threading.Timer` - but then I can't cancel the process if a condition is met.

Can someone suggest an elegant solution ?

Comment: You can check the condition after the timer is triggered (first action) and skip the processing if needed.

Comment: Looking for the Timer.Enabled property?  Or a while-statement in a Task with a Task.Delay() inside the loop?  The task is easier to stop reliably.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this easily using [Reactive Extensions](https://rehansaeed.com/reactive-extensions-part4-replacing-timers/):

```
int maxDurationInseconds = 5;
bool condition = true;

var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .TakeWhile(i => i <= maxDurationInseconds)
    .TakeWhile(i => condition)
    .Subscribe(i => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    });

Console.ReadLine();     

timer.Dispose();
```

The above code will show the elapsed seconds until the threshold is reached or the condition becomes false. `i` represent the amount of seconds passed.

A good reference for Rx can be found [here](http://www.introtorx.com/). Or take a look at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET).